# Problema al utilizar libreria PHPMailer

Tags: php

Saludos. Mi problema es el siguiente: estoy tratando de enviar correos electronicos desde mi pagina con la libreria PHPMailer, pero al presionar el boton de enviar me sale el siguiente error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\contact_me.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\contact_me.php on line 6**

Me esta diciendo que la clase PHPMailer no existe, no entiendo porque, estoy revisando el archivo en donde esta esa clase y esta todo bien.

Aqui dejo el codigo:

```
<?php 

include 'conexionbd.php';
include 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

$oMail = new PHPMailer();

$oMail->isSMTP();
$oMail->Host = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
$oMail->Username = '    45d7f968676e1e';
$oMail->Password = '166b3920081adc';

$oMail->SMTPAuth = true;
$oMail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$oMail->Port = 25;

//Datos

$name = $_POST['name'];
$oMail->From = $_POST['email']; //remitente
$oMail->addAddress('gpojava@gmail.com');
$oMail->Subject = 'HOLA JAVAEVENTOS SOY';
$mail->Body = $_POST['mensaje'];

$oMail->send();

if($oMail->send() == false){
    header('Location:socios.php');
    echo $oMail->ErrorInfo();
}else{
    header('Location:index.php');
}
```

reviso y reviso la carpeta de la librería y esta todo bien, entre en la documentación de PHPMailer y he hecho todo igual pero me sigue apareciendo este error. Por favor agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No parece que todos los archivos necesarios para usar esa clase estén presentes. Yo comenzaría de nuevo:

Descargue el paquete de https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer haciendo clic en el botón "Descargar ZIP" en la esquina inferior derecha de la página.
extraer el archivo zip

cargue la carpeta de idioma, class.phpmailer.php, class.pop3.php, class.smtp.php, y PHPMailerAutoload.php todo en el mismo directorio en su servidor, me gusta crear un directorio en el servidor llamado phpmailer para colocar todo de estos en.

Incluya la clase en su proyecto PHP:

```
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

Autor de la respuesta : [Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2460294/drew)

la pregunta fue esta : [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906487/fatal-error-class-phpmailer-not-found)